# How to properly implement onDestroy method?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, ondestroy

I'm developing an android application and i'm almost done, and in order to have a good application i wanted to know how to properly implement the onDestroy method, i mean do i have to call the garbage collector or set everything to null?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a database opened,or a opened cursor you can close them in onDestroy() method.System will automatically call gc when it is necessary.

Comment: yeah this is the kind of thing i was looking for.. and what the acitivities' members should i do something about them like calling gc or something?

Comment: you can System.gc() though it is done by system automatically when it needs to free some memory

Answer (score 1):

On Destroy method you can set null all and System.gc() for garbage collector,,,,,Mind that its not neccesary to set null Because java has this feature to null object using garbage collector..........